# Automatically posting language specific posts on Facebook fan page

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I know that on a Facebook fan page, if you want to make a post visible to only a specific set of people based on their facebook language we can do that. For Eg. If I want to post a post that is visible to only people who have set Facebook language to French, then I can set the "Make visible: language -> French" when I post it.

Now, I want to do this programmatically. I have 2 sets of text. I want to post one of them to a certain set of languages and other for just french. Say, first set for "English, Spanish, Polish" while the second set for just "French". How can I do this programmatically? Does facebook API allows us to do that?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know. [Does it](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/)?

Comment: And how do you know that I haven't researched? Sometimes you just need a fresh set of eyes/mind.

Comment: "Does facebook API allows us to do that?" If you had done your research the question would look more like "I've looked everywhere in the facebook API, but haven't found anything to point me in the right direction. Please help!"

Comment: I wanted to double check. After failing to get a solution, I started to doubt it. You said you dont want to be sarcastic or mean but you are. Sorry I wasted your time. And Sorry for not knowing that "Matt" needs clear language to know if I researched on my own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've not tried this but the documentation here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#posts seems to imply you can include a "targeting" property. Try playing around with that in the graph api explorer to see if it achieves what you are after. I'm assuming you know how to use the api as you merely mentioned the language side of it. If you don't know what you can do with the api then I suggest you check out the docs as mentioned by Matt in the comments